# How to display message on toast when raised button is clicked?

Tags: flutter, dart

When login button is pressed, I want to show a `toast` that displays user details in successful or "not found" message otherwise.

```
 new RaisedButton(
     onPressed: () {
        Future<User> user = _sendToServer();

        if (user != null) {
              Toast.show("You have logged as ${user.toString()}", context,
                  duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
        } else {
              Toast.show("Not found", context,
                  duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
        }
     },
     child: new Text('log in'),
  ),
```

I know that I receive the right response but just unable to display it using toast.

```
Future<User> _sendToServer() async {
  DatabaseHelper helper = DatabaseHelper.instance;
  if (_key.currentState.validate()) {
    // No any error in validation
    _key.currentState.save();
    User user = await helper.getLogin(email, password);
    print("login user ${user.email}");
    return user;
  } else {
    // validation error
    setState(() {
      _validate = true;
    });
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () async{ // mark it async
    User user = await _sendToServer(); // await to get user

    if (user != null) {
      Toast.show("You have logged as ${user.toString()}", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    } else {
      Toast.show("Not found", context,
          duration: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, gravity: Toast.BOTTOM);
    }
  },
  child: new Text('log in'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `onPressed` as async and call your function with await or use it like a promise.

For exa -

```
yourFunctiomWithFuture().then((value) {
    // Run code here
  }, onError: (error) {
    print(error);
  });
```